# Correct way to conduct multiple windows in Caliburn Micro?

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I am working on an app using Caliburn.Micro. I need to open a set of identical **windows** on multiple monitors at once, and I cannot figure out how to do this cleanly.

My idea is this:

- `ChildViewModel` / `ChildView` contains the things I need to show on multiple screens.
- `ParentViewModel` inheriting from `ConductorBase<ChildViewModel>`.
- When `ParentViewModel` is created, it creates the required number of `ChildViewModel` and uses `WindowManager.ShowWindow` to show each of them.
- My `WindowManager` implementation takes care of placing these views where they are supposed to be.

All of the above works, with one exception: the `ParentView` is displayed in its own window. How can I avoid this happening? what would be the canonical way of doing what I am trying to do?

What I want to do is conduct multiple windows from a single conductor, without the conductor itself showing a window.

Comment: what do you do to open this windows? clicking a button, starting your App?

Comment: Clicking a menu item from a notification area context menu. It shouldn't be relevant.

Comment: at this click you are raising a Command right? so you could "open" this windows in this command. I don't know how Caliburn handels this exactly but this Command would be the position where i would give it a try

Comment: I have no problem opening the windows. If you read the question, you will see that the problem is that it requires the ParentView to be visible at the same time.

Comment: i have seen it but maybe missed the point. why do you need a ParentViewModel/ParentView? what does it do?

Comment: All of the child windows should open and close as a unit. Close one, and all of them should close. The ParentViewModel enforces this through its role as a Conductor. So technically, I'd like to get rid of `ParentViewModel` and `ParentView`, and replace it with a `ParentConductor` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about this schema?

```
                          SystemTrayVM
      (VM for your notification area, its View is the sys tray icon)
                                |
                                |
                      MultipleDesktopManager
      (not a VM, not a ConductorBase, no View, not visible)
                                |
            .-------------------|------------------.
            |                   |                  |
            |                   |                  |
    SingleDesktopVM      SingleDesktopVM     SingleDesktopVM
(its View holds child views. If necessary, it can be a ConductorBase)
                                |
                  .-------------|------------.------ - - - .
                  |             |            |
                  |             |            |
         SideBarChildVM    MainChildVM   FooterChildVM
```

- *SystemTrayVM* is responsible for all interaction made available through the notification area (right click menu action, etc.). It would not actually open/close the windows visible to user, but rather forward those commands to the *MultipleDesktopManager*.
- *MultipleDesktopManager* is not visible and is not a VM. Its responsibility is to e.g. open/close all single desktop parent windows when needed. Being completely separate windows, there should be no need for a full blown conductor. From my experience, it is enough to provide it with an *IWindowManager* so that it can actually show/close the single desktop parent windows. Maybe it could also activate/deactivate them, but no need to keep track of a *current* active item or things like that.
- *SingleDesktopVM* is responsible for all the child views/VMs shown inside itself. So this could be a conductor if needed... it really depends on the lifecycle of those child views inside the parent. E.g. if there's a command-bar and a main content and they're always there, probably you could go with a simpler parent VM containing other VMs.

In a recent past we faced & solved the issue of a WPF application starting not visible, only found in system tray, and from there being able to show/hide the *actual* main application window.
In that scenario, we offloaded the task of hiding/showing the main app window to a helper class (not a VM) invoked by the SystemTrayVM. That would be the equivalent of *MultipleDesktopManager* in this schema.

Regarding the WPF application starting from system tray only, we put together a [PoC on GitHub](https://github.com/BrainCrumbz/caliburn-micro-wpf-notifyicon-poc) that shows how to completely integrate [this WPF NotifyIcon](http://www.hardcodet.net/wpf-notifyicon) control with a Caliburn.Micro ViewModel-first approach and DI through Autofac.

**EDIT**: The rationale is that Conductor implementations offered off the shelf by CM seem more adequate for a *window* holding other child *windows*. If the holder is not itself visible, maybe those conductor implementations are not the perfect choice. As you said in comments, it's like needing a Conductor **not being** also a Screen. There's an interesting bit on [CM composition doc page](http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/composition) about "Quasi-Conductors". In the end, the *MultipleDesktopManager* idea is basically that of a simple conductor that manages many windows, without implementing the *IConductor* interface but still using the *WindowManager* in order to process *SingleDesktopVMs* lifecycle correctly.

Comment: Thanks for this. I had already seen your work on Github, and use some of it. Your description was basically exactly what I was looking for. I've got this running well now, with one exception. Whenever I close the first window opened from the tray, the entire application exits. In the bootstrapper, I use the `NotificationIcon` from a resource. My `MultipleDesktopManager` uses `IWindowManager.ShowWindow(new SingleDesktopVM())` to start a window, and `vm.TryClose()` to close them.

Comment: Never mind my last comment. I obviously hadn't read all of the examples in the linked GitHub repos. For some reason I had implemented solution 3, thinking I didn't need a hosting window for the tray icon. But now I realise that the hidden window is what keeps the application running for as long as it is open. Thank you.

Comment: uhm... do you think that that 4-part PoC series might be misleading as is explained now? We put a *tl;dr;* at the beginning that basically says "skip to #4". Do you think we can improve that readme somehow? BTW, good to know that it helped.

Comment: Nope. This was just a case of me looking for something specific, and thinking I found it because I didn't read everything. A suggestion to make this more clear (but it involves a lot of work) is to have a git repository with branches/tags at the different levels, illustrating how you move from 1 to 4. :)

Comment: That's true, I've seen that done other times. For time being, I just went with a more *evident* disclaimer :) cheers

Answer (score -1):

Maybe i missed again something, but you could based on the infromation you provided do the follwing

Step 1.

- go to your class(VM) which handles your Menuclick
- add a private value `ParentConductor` which will do the same thing like your `ParentViewModel` does (holding a ref to each Child and close all if one was Closed)

Step 2.

- modify your MenuclickClickCommand so that each time you click it following happend
- int your `ParentConductor`
- creating your Child's and add ref to your `ParentConductor`
- use Caliburn to create windows foreach child

Now you should be able to close all Child's if one is closed.
there is no need to create a `ParentView` because your conductor will life as long as your class(VM) does.

You can also add a method so that the conductor could be able to delete him self from the class after he closed his Child's

Comment: Your answer generically lists what you would do to show a set of windows. The problem here is how to do it correctly following Caliburn.Micro's conventions. Code is required.

Comment: @VegardLarsen is there something special why you use `ConductorBase<T>` instead of `Conductor<T>` ?

Comment: No. Just convenience. My implementation is not necessarily correct, e.g. I think what I may really need is a stand-alone conductor that doesn't implement IScreen.